# Menu Dropdown com problema de propagation

Tags: javascript

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o porque ao clicar nas opções do menu, as vezes o container perde o hover e fecha o container?

Abaixo segue o meu código:

```
<style>
    ul.nav-menu__consultora,
ul.nav-menu__consultora ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul.nav-menu__consultora ul li{
    padding: 5px;       
}
.nav-menu__consultora{   
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu__consultor,
.opcao--queiro-consultor-type,
.opcao--soy-consultor-type{
    display: none;
}
.option-consultor:hover .menu__consultor,
.open{
    display: block;
}
.nav-menu__consultora li {
    list-style: none;
}
</style>
<nav class="menu-header__consultora">
    <ul class="nav-menu__consultora">
        <li class="option-consultor">Consultor(a)
            <ul class="menu__consultor">
                <li class="opcao--queiro-consultor opcao--consultor">Quiero ser Consultor(a)
                    <ul class="opcao--queiro-consultor-type opcao-type">
                        <li>Digital</li>
                        <li>Presencial</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="opcao--soy-consultor opcao--consultor"> Soy Consultor(a)
                    <ul class="opcao--soy-consultor-type opcao-type">
                        <li>Digital</li>
                        <li>Presencial</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script>
    var opcoesConsultor = document.querySelectorAll('.opcao--consultor');
    var opcoesType = document.querySelectorAll('.opcao-type');

    opcoesConsultor.forEach(function(opcao, i){
        opcao.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            opcoesType[i].classList.toggle('open');
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro primeiro criar uma *flag* (variável para controle) e criar um novo evento `click` para o menu `.menu__consultor` para alterar o valor da flag. O menu só irá se fechar quando a flag for `false`. Ao clicar na opções do menu, a flag vira `true` e em seguida `false` novamente. Desta forma, o menu não será fechado no click porque o `if` no `mouseout` não permitirá. Isso porque o evento `mouseout` é chamado quando você clica no menu.

**Veja:**

```js
var opcoesConsultor = document.querySelectorAll('.opcao--consultor');
var opcoesType = document.querySelectorAll('.opcao-type');
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu__consultor');
var flag = false; // flag

opcoesConsultor.forEach(function(opcao, i){
  opcao.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      opcoesType[i].classList.toggle('open');
      menu.classList.add('open');
  })
  opcao.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      menu.classList.add('open');
      flag = false;
  })
})

opcoesType.forEach(function(type, i){
  type.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      menu.classList.add('open');
      flag = false;
  })
})

menu.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
   if(!flag) menu.classList.remove('open');
})

// eventos adicionados
menu.addEventListener("click", function(){
   flag = true;
})

menu.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
   flag = false;
})
```

```css
ul.nav-menu__consultora,
ul.nav-menu__consultora ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.nav-menu__consultora ul li{
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.nav-menu__consultora{   
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu__consultor,
.opcao--queiro-consultor-type,
.opcao--soy-consultor-type{
  display: none;
  background: red; /* fundo vermelho apenas para ilustrar */
}
.option-consultor:hover .menu__consultor{
  display: block;
}
.open{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-header__consultora">
    <ul class="nav-menu__consultora">
        <li class="option-consultor">Consultor(a)
            <ul class="menu__consultor">
                <li class="opcao--queiro-consultor opcao--consultor">Quiero ser Consultor(a)
                    <ul class="opcao--queiro-consultor-type opcao-type">
                        <li>Digital</li>
                        <li>Presencial</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="opcao--soy-consultor opcao--consultor"> Soy Consultor(a)
                    <ul class="opcao--soy-consultor-type opcao-type">
                        <li>Digital</li>
                        <li>Presencial</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado dvd, deu certo man. Valeu mesmo.